# Check if all of the Enum values are not set

Tags: c#, enums, flags

Is it possible with a ONE-Liner (else the normal way...) to check if any of all possible enum states are set?

From enum fruits I want to know wether it is unset means no banana, no apple, no melon.

How can I do that?

Comment: It would help if you'd give a concrete example in terms of code - are you talking about a Flags enum, for example?

Comment: enumerations aren't really states, per se. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would:

`myFlags == 0`

Suffice?  0 represents no bits set, assuming you are using flags and not doing anything funky with the values.

Given this enum:

```
[Flags]
enum Fruit
{
    Forbidden = 0,
    Apple = 1,
    Orange = 2,
    Banana = 4
}
```

And this code:

```
Fruit f = Fruit.Apple | Fruit.Banana;

if (f == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("what?");

f = Fruit.Forbidden;

if (f == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("expected");
```

It does what you'd expect it to, however it is checking the underling value not doing bitwise ops, so if you mutate the underling value incorrectly you start to get issues, but you'll get other issues as well.

Given:

```
[Flags]
enum Fruit
{
    Apple = 1,
    Orange = 2,
    Banana = 4
}
```

And:

```
Fruit f = Fruit.Apple | Fruit.Banana;

if (f == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("what?");

f = f & ~Fruit.Apple & ~Fruit.Banana;

if (f == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("expected");
```

Also behaves.

Comment: Indeed, but if the flags enumeration was set, that wouldn't actually change any bits would it?  I can never remember this stuff!

Comment: Yeah, just warming up The Studio to have a look.  I'll amend my answer to suit.

Comment: OK I'll try removing that and see what's what.

Comment: I'm just saying that a more verbose meaning would be to either simply check if f == Fruit.Forbidden or check f with all possible bit flags.

Comment: Forbidden being the first in the list, would get a default value of 0 if not explicitly set. =)

Comment: @J. Steen: No, you can set it to whatever you want.

Comment: @0A0D, yes, but the *default* is 0.

Comment: @J. Steen: No one is talking about default except you :)

Comment: @You guys my StackExchange inbox is now full of your spam :-)

Comment: @Adam I liked the None as default most :) I dont use Flags just normal enum class

Answer (score 4):

```
[Flags]
enum Fruit
{
    None,
    Apple  /* = 1*/,
    Orange    = Apple << 1,
    Banana    = Orange << 1,

    All       = (Banana << 1) -1
}
```

This way you could check whether

- no fruit flags are set: `value == Fruit.None`
- *all* fruit flags are set: `value == Fruit.All`
- illegal fruit values are set: `(value & ~Fruit.All) != 0`

See this on [IdeOne](https://ideone.com/lHuQZ)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about an enumeration that is setup as Bit Flags, [MSDN has a good example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx):

```
[Flags]
enum Days2
{
    None = 0x0,
    Sunday = 0x1,
    Monday = 0x2,
    Tuesday = 0x4,
    Wednesday = 0x8,
    Thursday = 0x10,
    Friday = 0x20,
    Saturday = 0x40
}
```

to check whether a bit flag is set, you could, for example do this:

```
// Test value of flags using bitwise AND.
bool test = (meetingDays & Days2.Thursday) == Days2.Thursday;
```

In theory, you could put all of your bitwise operations on one line separated by an `&` or `|` depending on your intent.

Comment: Sorry if you haven't edited, must have miss-read it the first time (i viewed the page). Thought i saw `meetingDays = Days2.Tuesday | Days2.Thursday;`

Comment: @George: Oh okay. No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that the enum contain a default, "non set" member such as `Fruit.None` with the value of `0` or `0x0`. That way, any "non set" member with the type of enum `Fruit` could be set as default to `Fruit.None`.

```
public enum Fruit
{
    None,
    Banana,
    Apple,
    Kumquat,
}
```

And

```
public class Meal
{
    Fruit myFruit = Fruit.None;
}
```